# Flag which shows compilation process

Tags: gcc, llvm, preprocessor

Is there a define / flag in the compilers (gcc, VS, LLVM) which is only set when they are active / compiling?
It should be similar to the doxygen DOXYGEN define when running.
I want to do some preprocessing and don't want to announce this special flag in the IDE.

Comment: You mean you searching for _compiler predefined macros_?

Comment: I mean something which adds e.g. gcc automatically as -D.

Comment: So did you try google? Like "[gcc compiler predefined macros](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+compiler+predefined+macros)"?

Comment: Perfect.
Thank you.
And yes I googled but maybe used the wrong wording.

Comment: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/j/guide-to-predefined-macros-in-c-compilers-gcc-clang-msvc-etc..html